# Which of the properties reflexive, symmetric, anti-symmetric and transitive does these relations have?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, notation, relations, equivalence-relations

Which of the properties reflexive, symmetric, anti-symmetric and transitive have the relations $R$, $S$, and $T$ below?

a) $X$ is the set of all functions $f: \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, and $f \sim_R g$ if $\frac{f}{g}$ is an odd function.

I have been stuck on this question for a day now, it is not even the question I am finding hard to answer, I just simply don't understand what they mean here. Can someone give me something to go on. Like what is meant by $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, what does $\setminus$ represent in this case?

Comment: $X$ is the set of all functions $f$ from the _nonzero_ real numbers to the _nonzero_ real numbers such that $f/g$ is an odd function.

Comment: The \ is set subtraction so it's $\mathbb{R}$ without $0$.

Comment: If you don't understand a bit of notation, I strongly recommend clearing that up before spending a full day on a question.

Comment: Clearer version of what @DilipSarwate tried to say: $X$ is the set of functions from nonzero reals to nonzero reals; for $f,\,g\in X$, $fRg$ iff $f/g$ is odd.